# How to save an Array like list view?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Entry, A save button and a list view. when a user add an entry to this list how can I save the preferences so next time I come back to the app, the List is not resets.
I have create a view model for this Job.

```
class EmploeeViewModel
    {
        public ICommand AddLinacCommand => new Command (AddLinac);
        public ObservableCollection<string> Emploees { get; set; }
        public string LinacName { get; set; }

        public EmploeeViewModel()

        {
            Emploees = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Emploees.Add("Behzad.C");
            Emploees.Add("Abolfazl.N");
            Emploees.Add("Samira.Y");

        }
        public void AddLinac()
        {
            Emploees.Add(LinacName);
        }
    }
}
```

(SO I want this void Addlinac Save the user entry for all Times)??????????????

Comment: use a SQLite db.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android) is a good solution to handle this.

However , the plugin [does not support to store array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android#supported-data-types) , so we have to convert the array into json string first using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) .

#### Store

```
ObservableCollection<string> Emploees = new ObservableCollection<string>();
Emploees.Add("Behzad.C");
Emploees.Add("Abolfazl.N");
Emploees.Add("Samira.Y");


string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Emploees);
Preferences.Set("my_key", json);
```

#### Get

```
var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");
var Emploees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myValue);
```

##### Update

//usage in viewmodel

```
class EmploeeViewModel
    {
        public ICommand AddLinacCommand => new Command(AddLinac);
        public ObservableCollection<string> Emploees { get; set; }
        public string LinacName { get; set; }

        public EmploeeViewModel()
        {

            var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");

            if(myValue != "default_value")
            {
                Emploees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myValue) as ObservableCollection<string>;
            }
            else
            {
                Emploees = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            }

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Emploees);
            Preferences.Set("my_key", json);
        }
        public void AddLinac()
        {
            Emploees.Add(LinacName);

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Emploees);
            Preferences.Set("my_key", json);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you man I will try tp test it and send results.

Comment: No problem, if you have any other question please let me know.

Comment: Colex sorry man, but get wired errors. would you plz rewrite my code above.

Comment: I have successfully convert my Array with newton.soft. but i cant recall it.  where should i use this---->          var Emploees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myValue)

Comment: At anywhere you want to get the value .

Comment: how can I use it in my viewmodel ?

Comment: Can anyone help me update the above MVVM code to call preferences?? i cant call jsonconvert.deserializeobject in  my                                                                          
public ObservableCollection<string> Emploees { get; set; }

Comment: Thank you very much ColeX, Your are the one.